# Explain microservice architecture

Tags: microservices

I am a beginner for microservices. I am taking the below image for questions reference.
[image]

1. In this diagram Account Service, Inventory service & Shipping services are accepting http requests, which means each service consists of separate server (e.g nginx) and backend code logic. Please correct if wrong.
2. If I create multiple instance of these services for scalability there will be separate load balancer for each service (e.g. Account service) and each instance will have a separate server instance (e.g. nginx) with it. Please correct if wrong.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both of your question is "can be the case, but not necessarily".

That's one of the great advantages of a microservide-based architecture: You are very flexible when it comes to deciding what runs on what server. Cheap and rarely used services can share the same hardware. Performance-hungry and frequently used services can run on multiple servers hidden behind a load-balancer.